# Как посчитать количество символов используя только charAt?

Tags: java

Можно использовать только метод charArt, циклы и операторы. Использовать метод string length() нельзя. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала читаем [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) метода `charAt()`

> Throws:
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index argument is negative or **not less than the length of this string**.

> Исключения:
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - если значение аргумента отрицательно или **не меньше длины этой строки**

Теперь пишем простой код

```java
int getStringLength(String str) {
  int res = 0;
  try {
    while (true) {
      str.charAt(res);
      res++;
    }
  } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
  return res;
}
```

Запускаем бесконечный цикл и последовательно пытаемся получить символы строки. Если поднялось исключение, значит была попытка получить символ за пределами строки.

Comment: Большое спасибо за решение! Хотелось бы понять, что означает 'e' в (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) ? Программа работает и с (IndexOutOfBoundsException index).

Comment: 'e' это ссылка на объект типа IndexOutOfBoundsException, название может быть любым, но так устоялось что у всех используется буква e